# Responsive File manager for Tinymce error 403

Tags: php, tinymce, responsive-filemanager

I am using [Responsive File manager](http://www.responsivefilemanager.com/index.php) for Tinymce on a project but i get an 403 error on upload.php (Firebug)

It is only this file that gives me the error I have already checked the file permissions and checked the owner. The paths on the `config.php` is fine, every thing works except for the upload.

The error Responsive File manager give me:

```
Forbidden You don't have permission to access  /admin/modules/tinymce/plugins/responsivefilemanager/filemanager/upload.php on this server.
```

Additionally, a `404 Not Found` error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Any Ideas?
Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you by chance on green geeks? I have been researching and realized its a lot of people on green geeks and other cpanel.

Comment: what is the current file permission of `upload.php` ?